# Cannot resolve symbol Theme

Tags: android, android-studio

Ошибка в **Андроид Студио**:

> Cannot resolve symbol Theme

в файле: styles.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо выполнить:

> Sync Project with Gradle Files