# Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme'

Tags: android, android-studio

Пишу приложение. Компилируется, работает. Но в файле `styles.xml` студия подчеркивает `Theme` с описанием ошибки:

> Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Пробовал что советовали [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773718/cannot-resolve-symbol-theme) - не помогло.

Версия: *Android Studio 3.1.2*.

В файле `build.gradle` так:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Выполните `Build => Rebuild Project`, если не поможет, можно указать в полном формате `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Или забить, раз уж сборке проекта это не мешает.

Comment: Выполнение Build => Rebuild Project и указание в полном формате, никак не помогли.

Comment: Ну тогда может пора перейти на `appcompat-v7:27.1.1` и `...SdkVersion 27` ;)? Попробуйте ещё грохнуть кэш `File => Invalidate caches / Restart... => Invalidate and restart`, прогнать инспектора `Analyze => Inspect Code...`.

Comment: File => Invalidate caches / Restart пробовал, не помогало тоже. Помог только Reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click File > Close Project

Reopen the project from Studio's dialog.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло.

Answer (score 2):

Мне помогло удалить содержимое папки `.idea/libraries`, после чего `Rebuild Project`